# Updating partitioned and clustered table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've created a partitioned and clustered BigQuery table for the time period of the year 2019, up to today. I can't seem to find if it is possible to update such a table (since I would need to add data for each new day). Is it possible to do it and if so, then how?

I've tried searching stackoverflow and BigQuery documentation for the answer. No results there on my part.

Comment: You can update tables in BigQuery, so I'm not sure what your question is.  You use `UPDATE`, just as you would with any other database.

Comment: either INSERT, UPDATE or MERGE statements work for you.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

Comment: But what happens with clustering when I update the table? Is the clustering done again automatically when I update the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data#updating_data) statement to update this data. Your partitioned table will maintain their properties across all operations that modify it, like the DML and DDL statements, load jobs and copy jobs as well. For more information, you could check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#clustering_partitioned_tables).

Hope it helps.